# Salesforce SOQL returning wrong set

Tags: java, salesforce, soql

I am executing a SOQL and when I am firing

`SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Contact`

then it's returning 12958 no of result set but when I am firing

```
SELECT LastName, ts2__Text_Resume__c FROM Contact
```

then only 890 results are coming, though size of result set in 2nd query is more then 4mb, so I am wondering why 2nd query giving lesser number of rows. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Considered `IsDeleted` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to consider two JSON object nextRecordsUrl, done as well when we get response and once we check done is true then all result set has been fetched.

Answer (score 0):

results are paged, so you got 890 rows in the first page, then you need to call queryMore to get the next page of results. see the examples in the docs on query/query/queryResult.